# How to store git repos of abandoned projects?

Tags: git

I have over 200 projects on my workstation, every one is a git repository. Most of them are superseded or otherwise abandoned. I still keep the code in case I ever need anything from them.

Currently, the active projects are non-bare git repositories in `~/Projects`, the inactive projects are `.tar.gz` archives that simply contain the whole non-bare git repository within the same folder. So I got the following:

- `~/Projects/some-active/.git`
- `~/Projects/some-inactive.tar.gz`

The advantage of this is that backups are really fast, inactive projects are just a single file which has to be checked/copied. Whenever I want to look into the projects, I have to extract the folder, look into it and compress it some time later when I think the project is inactive again.

Is there a better way to this?

Comment: You could put the inactive projects in .gitignore and they wouldn't need to be compressed because they won't be syncing. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: I do my backups with `rsync`, so I would need to exclude them there. But I do want the backup to be consistent, so I would like to avoid adding things to the backup ignore file. There is no super-repository in the ~/Projects` folder.

Comment: Push them to bitbucket.

Comment: I just put them in an `obsolete` directory. I don't think there's really a reason to treat them specially elsewise. I don't delete them since the code might still come in handy some day.

Comment: @simonzack, why not have an `obsolete` repo, then have each obsolete project as a submodule?

Comment: @trysis I don't really see the point of keeping track of the history of whether a project is active, backup's enough for me on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First suggestion: Just keep them the same way as active repositories, except make sure all objects are in a single packfile (`git gc` will do that). rsync mostly just checks modification times; it doesn't read the whole file if everything else matches; it *shouldn't* be slow. (My backup consists of rsyncing over 1M files, many of which are Git repositories, and it's still acceptably fast...)

Second suggestion: Keep them as *bare* repositories. Whenever you want to look at the files, use `tig`'s "tree browser" mode, or clone to /tmp (e.g. `git clone -s ~/Projects/foo.git /tmp/foo`). This way, each repo will have only about 5 files (packfile, pack index, config, packed-refs).

Comment: Keeping them all as active is probably the easiest solution to it. Running `git gc --aggressive` on them regularly can be done with a script. [“Simple is better than complex.”](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @queueoverflow: If you don't commit, then it's enough to do `git gc` just once...

Comment: I have a job that runs `git gc --aggressive` on all the git repos every month or so. That way I do not have to remember to do this manually.